# How to download a zipfile from a Github repository

Tags: wget, zip, github

I'm trying to download a zipfile from a Github repository with this command:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/brendenlake/omniglot/blob/master/python/images_evaluation.zip -O /tmp/images_evaluation.zip
```

But it doesn't download a valid zip file. I suppose that it downloads the HTML file that the browser shows if you click on the url.

How can I download a zip file from a public Github repository using wget?

Answer (score 3):

I have found the answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/387912/132714

I have changed the `blob`:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/brendenlake/omniglot/blob/master/python/images_evaluation.zip -O /tmp/images_evaluation.zip
```

With `raw`:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/brendenlake/omniglot/raw/master/python/images_evaluation.zip -O /tmp/images_evaluation.zip
```

And now it downloads a valid zip file.

Answer (score 1):

try using  `git clone` instead of `wget`